# Is There an Erlang BERT-RPC Client?

Tags: erlang, bert-rpc

If I have a BERT-RPC Server (Ernie) on one machine, and would like to communicate with it from an Erlang/OTP application from another machine, what would be the best course? Is There an Erlang BERT-RPC Client?

I suppose it wouldn't be too much trouble to send and receive messages via gen_tcp, but is there an existing, stable application for this already?

Answer (score 2):

We run a simple `gen_server` using `gen_tcp` to handle incoming bert requests from Rails apps. Somewhere in there you find something like:

```
handle_info({tcp, Socket, RawData}, State) ->
    Data = bert:decode(RawData),
    do_bert_crap(Data),
    ...
    gen_tcp:send(Socket, bert:encode({reply, whatever})),
    {noreply, State}.
```

We don't handle many requests this way. This is used internally only.

Edit: We use [bert.erl](https://github.com/mojombo/bert.erl) for (de-)serialization.

Comment: What about {active, false} version? I've read that {active, true} may be vulnerable on huge traffic, because it makes messages.